# How can I develop $f(x) = (x^2+1)\cdot \arctan(x)$ into a Taylor series about $x_{0} = 0$?

Tags: calculus

How can I develop $f(x) = (x^2+1)\cdot \arctan(x)$ into a Taylor series about $x_{0} = 0$ ?

I see that $f(x) = \frac{\arctan(x)}{\arctan'(x)}$ and I also know what the Taylor expansion of $\arctan(x)$ looks like about zero. But I don't know how to develope what they wanted. I get a series that is not a power series...

Answer (score 2):

The key here is that you want the same power of $x$ for all the terms of the sum.

\begin{align*}
(x^2+1)\arctan(x) & = (x^2+1) \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}\\
& =  \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+3}}{2k+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}\\
& = \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+3}}{2k+1}+\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}+x\\
& =\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+3}}{2k+1}-\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+3}}{2k+3}+x\\
& =x+\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^k \left(\frac{1}{2k+1}-\frac{1}{2k+3}\right)x^{2k+3} 
\end{align*}

Comment: Can you explain the transition from $k = 1$ to $k = 0$ ?

Comment: I think the $+1$ should be $+x$.  Let $h=k-1$, then the second sum should become $\sum_{h=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^{h+1}\frac{x^{2h+3}}{2h+3}$, or you could just use $k$ again, instead of $h$, as he did.  I think $(-1)^{k+1}=-(-1)^k$ means the sign should change.

Comment: Yes, corrected. Thank you. :)

Comment: Amir : In general we have $\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} a_k = \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} a_{k-1}$. Try to expand the two sums to see that they are equal. That's what I used.

Answer (score 0):

Simply multiply each term in $\arctan(x)$ by $x^2+1$, then collect like terms.

Comment: That's what I did but then I don't get a power series around zero... I get a weird thing

Comment: What did you get?

Comment: I get: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n (x^{2n+1} + x^{2n + 3})}{2n+1}$

Comment: The $x^{2n+3}$ for $n=k$ goes with the $x^{2n+1}$ for $n=k+1$.  For example, your first term has $x$ and $x^3$, and the second term has $x^3$ and $x^5$.  Put the $x^3$s together.

Comment: How? I can't manage to do that =(

Comment: $x^{2k+3}$ appears in the $n=k$ term, multiplied with $(-1)^k/(2k+1)$, and also in the $n=k+1$ term, when $2n+1=2k+3$, and multiplied with $(-1)^{k+1}/(2k+3)=-(-1)^k/(2k+3)$.  The total is $(-1)^k(\frac1{2k+1}-\frac1{2k+3})$

Answer (score 0):

$$f'(x)=2x\tan^{-1}x+1$$
$$f'(x)=1+2x\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac{{{(-1)}^{n+1}}}{(2n-1)}}\,{{x}^{2n-1}}=1+2\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac{{{(-1)}^{n+1}}}{(2n-1)}}\,{{x}^{2n}}$$ therefore
$$f(x)=c+x+2\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac{{{(-1)}^{n+1}}}{(2n+1)(2n-1)}}\,{{x}^{2n+1}}$$ 
we have $f(0)=0$, thus $c=0$ and we have
$$f(x)=x+2\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac{{{(-1)}^{n+1}}}{(2n+1)(2n-1)}}\,{{x}^{2n+1}}$$